# Possible up-vote abuse?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

The question I came across in New Question queue, looked so horrific I didn't dare rate it; I just put in my rash opinion as a comment.  I glanced at it later, and it had 2 up-votes.  Knowing a bit about folks perusing new questions, I'm kind of surprised it got up-voted twice in a day.  Did the poster have some friends up-vote it perhaps?

Post: [Optimizing queries using indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/321579/optimizing-queries-using-indexes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I, too, often wonder why people upvote questions that to me seem to be of low quality. But then I remind myself: It's the internets; people upvote junk all the time for whatever reasons. If you don't like the question, downvote and move along. Or just move along. Your time is not worth somebody's two extra unicorn points.

Comment: I upvoted this answer even though I hate it. I just really love mustaches.

Comment: Question up votes award 10 points these days. It used to be 5.

Answer (score 7):

> The question I came across in New Question queue, looked so horrific...

Horrific? In my estimation, that question is *above average* for its type.

It explains the problem clearly, admits it is coursework, provides DDL and sample data, shows what they have tried, and why it seems inadequate. Given that we [allow 'homework' style questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/490), what more could we ask of the querent here?

> ...I didn't dare rate it

Why ever not? The voting system exists for many reasons. One is to give feedback to the writer - a down vote suggests something ought to be improved in someone's opinion. Voting on questions is also free. I am honestly at a loss to comprehend the source of your fear here.

> I just put in my rash opinion as a comment.

Yeah, well please don't do that. It's counterproductive for many reasons, see [Is the comment-only answer acceptable?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3020/is-the-comment-only-answer-acceptable) in the FAQ.

Your 'comment' would be better as an answer (of the frame-challenge variety), which people could then vote on as they feel it deserves (up *or* down).

> Did the poster have some friends up-vote it perhaps?

Not that I can see. It seems two other people disagreed with your assessment and found it to be worthy of an upvote.

---

Returning to the question of the quality of the question, or its suitability for the site. As far as I can discern from your comment, it seems you disagree with the question they have been set, or the way it ought to be answered.

You might have a point there, but it's one the asker is unlikely to be able to 'fix'. The question they have been set is what it is. You might not like it, or think it is relevant given your particular real-world experience. Well, fair enough.

Comment: Very helpful.  This will help me in reviews. Thanks!